# Update single column based on 2 different databases table data

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I create a single query to update data based on column id?

DB1.Users

| userid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | asd |
| 2 | qwe |

BD2.users

| userid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | zxc |
| 3 | fff |

for example

```
update DB2.USERS.NAME TO "X"
WHERE DB1.USERS.USERID doesn't exist in DB2.USER.USERID.
```

the expected result should be "fff" to "X" but there is a story there which is also "zxc" updated to "X"

is there a solution that solves it in a single query

Comment: sorry but this doesnt make sense.  you should try to be more clear on the expected result.  Your example of zxc should NOT be updated based on your first statement since there is that id in the other table.

Comment: In the second part of the example, you update the `fff` value from `DB2`. But in the first part of the example you say you want to update `DB1`, which would be the `asd` value. Which is correct?

Comment: i tried to run this query but all records updated then i tried to select query instead of update but the results are duplicates of all databases table columns

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the the first part is the correct one I had update it thanks for letting me know

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but only if the two databases are in the same server and the user account running the query has rights in both databases:

```
UPDATE DB2.USERS
   SET NAME = 'X'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DB1.Users u1 WHERE u1.UserID = DB2.Users.UserID)
```

If the databases are on different servers, you might try [Federation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html).

Comment: still not getting the expected result but I rollback this query and I tried to make a select query instead of an update but there is 0 record returned but by logically it has to be done that way